# Display varchar Date as D/M/Y?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc-3, datetime-format

I am pulling a date out of a database and it is a varchar. However in the database it is formatted Y/M/D/. I need it to render on the front end a D/M/Y. I am bring it into Linq using Entity framework. It looks like this:

var startdateParam = new ObjectParameter("StartDate", typeof (string));

I then call the stored procedure:

```
  var webinarProducts = mgr.GetWebinars(groupCodeParam, startdateParam).ToList();
```

I then assign it to my product list:

webinar.StartDate = startdateParam.Value.ToString();

Finally, in the cshtml file ( I am building this in MVC3) I display like this:

@Model.StartDate

But when I publish the page it just formats as the wierd date inside the Data table Y/M/D.

I've tried to convert/parse/format this all over my code but I keep getting errors. What's the best way to convert this to whatever date format I would like?

Comment: What errors? What have you tried as far as datetime.parse?

Comment: Why is your date field in the database as a varchar in the first place? If you can possibly fix the schema, that would be the best approach.

Comment: I can fix it. It's client database. I cant change anything.

Comment: @Aaron: I just get red squiggly's from visual studio. I've tried:          Where(p => Convert.ToDateTime(p.StartDate) andit says this in not a a method. Is there some way to do this in my stored procedure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use built-in parsing?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx

Format strings here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

```
webinar.StartDate = DateTime.ParseExact(startdateParam.Value.ToString(), "yyyy/MM/dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Then in the front end you can specify

```
@Model.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
```

Comment: Thanks eouw0o83hf. I tried this and I get this error again:      "An instance of type 'System.DateTime' cannot be assigned to variable of type string.   This is the same error I get wherever I try to convert to datetime.

Comment: Copy/paste in the code you're using to convert to the string - I'll bet there's a syntax error we can debug

Comment: I assume that's because webinar.StartDate is a string?  If that's the case, you might want to consider changing it to a `System.DateTime` and then use the code above.

Comment: var startdateParam = new ObjectParameter("StartDate", typeof (string));                                                          var webinarProducts = mgr.GetWebinars(groupingCodeParam, startdateParam).ToList();                                           webinar.StartDate = DateTime.ParseExact(startdateParam.Value.ToString(), "yyyy/MM/dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);  The StartTimeIS a string already. I just want to literally change it to any date format i want.

Comment: I am guessing that John Ruiz is right - is StartDate a string or DateTime? If you change the property to a DateTime, it will likely work.

Comment: It is a string. I see what you mean now. Change the public string {get; set;} property to a datetime. Even though in the database it is a var char? I will give this a try. thank you.

Comment: Yes. The very best solution would be to change the database type to a Date or DateTime; however, assuming that is not possible or out of scope, changing the C# property to a DateTime is definitely the right thing to do - that way you can treat it as a proper date from that point on after you parse it.

Comment: I changed the C# property to datetime. I didn't get any errors in code so I was hopeful. But it displayed no data at all. Should I change typeof (string) to datetime as well? tried that. same results. Im stumped.

Comment: No - your problem is probably now on the front end, in getting the date out to a string. What does your view code look like? It should probably be something like:

@Model.StartDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")

Comment: Tried keeping everything as string. Then tried webinar.StartDate = String.Format(startdateParam.Value.ToString(), "yyyy/MM/dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); In my razor view I get an error for  <li>@Model.StartDate.ToString("dd/MM/yy"); </li> The error is: The best overloaded method match for 'string.ToString(System.IFormatProvider)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: StartDate must be a DateTime. The Razor view is trying to call ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") on a string, when it's expecting a DateTime, which is why it's failing.

Comment: Ok. to be clear. Even though the date is stored in the database as a varchar. I'm bringing it in as a stored proc using entity framework. In my properties i should explicitly chnage the format to DATETIME? correct? then follow your code and it should work. I will try all these things again. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yeah again, I followed everything and no data shows up. hhmm.

Comment: Ok. Successfully converted the varchar to datetime in stored proc. I run the code above and debug error says:String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Answer (score 1):

If you can change the schema, I would use a DATETIME column instead of varchar.

If not, I would use the built in DateTime functions in C#. This code should work:

```
DateTime dateObj = DateTime.Parse(startdateParam.Value.ToString());
string outDateString = dateObj .ToString("dd/MM/yy");
```

Hope that helps.